# Pandas: Como mesclar dois data frames?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Bom dia Pessoal! Conto com a ajuda de vocês novamente.

Tenho 2 CSV, como abaixo:

```
# f1.csv
num   ano
76971  1975
76969  1975
76968  1975
76966  1975
76964  1975
76963  1975
76960  1975
```

e

```
# f2.csv
num   ano   dou  url
76971  1975 p1   http://exemplo.com/page1
76968  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page10
76966  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page100
```

Como posso mesclar os dois desta maneira?

```
# resultado esperado
num   ano   dou  url
76971  1975 p1   http://exemplo.com/page1
76969  1975
76968  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page10
76966  1975 p2   http://exemplo.com/page100
76964  1975
76963  1975
76960  1975
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens a maneira mais direta, cuja a solução foi inspirada [aqui (vários exemplos de sql convertidos em pandas)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html#left-outer-join), neste caso queremos o [`left join`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) ou `outer join` neste caso:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('f1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('f2.csv')

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['num', 'ano'], how="left") # colocamos o ano só para ser ignorado, em vez disto podiamos fazer df2.drop(['ano'], axis=1, inplace=True) para dropar a coluna do ano de df2
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     num   ano  dou                         url
0  76971  1975   p1    http://exemplo.com/page1
1  76969  1975  NaN                         NaN
2  76968  1975   p2   http://exemplo.com/page10
3  76966  1975   p2  http://exemplo.com/page100
4  76964  1975  NaN                         NaN
5  76963  1975  NaN                         NaN
6  76960  1975  NaN                         NaN
```

Se em vez de `NaN` quiseres uma string fazia, podes depois só:

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/@mf1985/FullPunyCone)

[DOCS merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
[DOCS fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)